# Contain items with dynamic height in VC with scrollable functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Here is an image of what I'm envisioning.
[image]

Two bottoms at the bottom will always stay there. And height of textview and container view is dynamic. I will container another viewcontroller in container view. When sum of height of textview and container view is bigger than current viewcontroller's height, I want them to be scrollable.

I've been looking into 2 things: UICollectionView, UIScrollView.
However, I could not figure out how to make what I'm envisioning with those two components.

I also tried with stackview but that was not suitable for my purposes.

My gut tells me that UIScrollView is way to go but I cannot figure out. My current attempt was putting a scroll view and set the constraints to Nav bar and 2 buttons. Then, put textview and container view inside scroll view using storyboard.

If somebody can guide me a bit, that would be super helpful to me. Sorry for not containing any code, btw. I just couldn't even start :/

Answer (score 0):

```
let margin = CGFloat(10)

let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake())//Set textViewFrame
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x:margin, y: textView.height + margin, width: view.frame.width - 2 * margin, height: view.frame.height)

let button1 = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(x:margin, y: textView.height + contentView.height + 2 * margin, width: (view.frame.width - 2 * margin) /2, height: 30)

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: button1.frame.origin.y + button1.frame.height + margin)
```

That should be enough to get you started. The important thing is adjusting the scrollView's content size to extend past the frame of the view. To test where this would get you you still need to add as subviews and you could also set backround colors different colors and adjust as necessary.

Comment: In this case, should I not use auto-layout?

Comment: This is just a programatic example, You can do autolayout its the same concept.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how I can set content size larger than the frame of the view in storyboard. Do I just make the size of container view bigger?

Comment: You can set it progromatically or there should be some setting on the right in attributes selector that lets your view controller be free form instead of fixed size.

Comment: I did solve most of problems except one, making height of textview dynamic. Can you please take a look at my next question if you have knowledge in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236967/setting-dynamic-height-on-uitextview-to-fit-content-programmatically