# Setting dynamic height on UItextview to fit content programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Just by programmatically coding, I'm trying to achieve something like below image. TextView and ContainerView are embedded in scrollview although it is not shown in the image.

[image]

Here is my code for this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let margin = CGFloat(10)
    textView =  UITextView()
    textView.text = "asdadaasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadaadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadadasdadadaddadd"
let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
textView.frame = CGRectMake(margin, 0, self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin, contentSize.height)


let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 50))
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(margin, contentSize.height + margin, self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin, self.view.frame.height))

let button1 = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(margin, contentSize.height + containerView.frame.height + 2 * margin, (view.frame.width - 2 * margin)/2, 30))

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: button1.frame.origin.y + button1.frame.height + margin)

self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(textView)
scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

The problem is that textview's height is not dynamic to show all content in textview.

I've confirmed that if I add below code in viewdidappear, it does make the height of textview dynamic but it is stacked under Container view because below code runs after ViewDidLoad configured everything.

```
let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
textView.frame = CGRectMake(margin, 0, self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin, contentSize.height)
```

What would be the best approach for this kind of problem?
I think this is caused due to rendering order in viewdidload but I'm not 100% sure. It would be great if someone can talk about rendering order too.

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need to lay things out programmatically? That can make things very difficult. Why not just use constraints?

Comment: @Dan, Tried using constraints and it was more painful than writing in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question, your call to **sizeThatFits** has no idea how tall the TextView should be because it has no idea how wide you want it to be. I think before the **sizeThatFits** line you want the following:

```
textView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin
```

Comment: That was it. But do I need to write this line after sizeThatFits again? textView.frame = CGRectMake(margin, 0, self.view.frame.width - 2 * margin, contentSize.height)  I feel like I'm duplicating width part. Would there be a better way for refactoring this?

Comment: Well true the width part is duplicated there, but the other properties need to be set (x, y, height.) x & y are 0 by default though, so really you could replace that with textView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height